# Griffon command line arguments

Tags: griffon

How to use getStartupArgs()

Since 0.9.1 it seems you can read the command line arguments [issue #245](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRIFFON-245) with the getStartupArgs() method ([documentation](http://griffon.codehaus.org/Griffon+0.9.1))

But I do know how to use it, I've put it in in all the Griffon lifecycle, Controller, Service, and I get the exception

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [LifeCycle|Controller|Service].getStartupArgs() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [LifeCycle|Controller|Service].getStartupArgs() is applicable for argument types: () values: [
```

]

Comment: I've tried all this versions 0.9.1a, 0.9.2-beta-2, 0.9.2-beta-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.getStartupArgs()

That's the way you can read the arguments